# How do I grab and send a dropdown's display text instead of value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this bit of jquery to put the value selected from my dropdown into a hidden text field.  This works beautifully - got it from one of the folks on this forum!!!, but I just ran into a twist further in my code and I need to do the same thing, but this time I neeed to send the **Display Text** to another hidden filed that I will create.  Using this code, what do I change to grab the **display text** instead of the associated value.  **for example if I have:**

```
<select id="firstbox">
<option value="TM">Time Warner</option>
<option value="CC">Comcast</option>
<option value="HC">Hartford Cable</option>
</select>
```

**How do alter the code below to grab and send "Time Warner", "Comcast" or "Hartford Cable"?**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select#2135, select#4436, select#4437").change(function(){
            $("#4443").val($(this).val());
        })
        .trigger('change');
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.text()` instead of `.val()` on the selected option

```
$(this).find(":selected").text()
```

---

*`ids` should start with a letter, too*

Comment: I know, whoever originally created this app used numbers, so I am stuck.