# Show <option> text instead of "value" value using JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have created a webapp using servlet and jsp where I have a dropdown tag in html as below

```
<select id='check' name='select1'>
<option value='1'>text1</option>
<option value='2'>text2</option>
</select>
```

how can I access a `TEXT` not `VALUE` from select box using javascript?

so I can display  `text1` or `text2` instead of 1 & 2, in my webapp.

I tried doing this, but it always gives me the "value" text not the option text?

```
 <%
       String checkText= request.getParameter("select1");
 %>
<script>
      document.getElementById("check").value = '<% out.print(checkText); %>';
</script>
```

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using jquery check this [How do I grab and send a dropdown's display text instead of value using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247508/how-do-i-grab-and-send-a-dropdowns-display-text-instead-of-value-using-jquery)